# Win Server 2003 r2: Can you deploy files without using GPP?

Tags: file-sharing, active-directory, group-policy

Im trying to deploy an email signature that needs to be placed in every C:%APPDATA%\MICROSOFT\Signatures folder on each machine in my domain. I am aware of how to deploy programs with .msi file extensions, but is it possible to deploy other files *not* associated with .msi?

*UPDATED QUESTION*

It's worth mentioning that I am running Windows Server 2003 R2. I found an article explaining that you can't edit preferences if you're using any server OS less than 2008. - http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/12/group-policy-preferences-prerequisites/

So, that being said: Is it even possible to deploy files without using GPP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can deploy any file via group policy. Take a look at this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772536%28v=ws.11%29.aspx).

Instructions copied below:

1. Open the **Group Policy Management Console**. Right-click the Group Policy object (GPO) that should contain the new preference item, and then click **Edit**.
2. In the console tree under **Computer Configuration** or **User Configuration** , expand the **Preferences** folder, and then expand the **Windows Settings** folder.
3. Right-click the **Files** node, point to **New** , and select **File** .
4. In the **New File Properties** dialog box, select an Action for Group Policy to perform. (you probably want "Create" in this case)
5. Enter file settings for Group Policy to configure or remove. (For more information, see "File settings" in the article)
6. Click the **Common** tab, configure any options, and then type your comments in the Description box. (For more information, see Configure Common Options in the article.)
7. Click **OK**. The new preference item appears in the details pane.

**Note** at the time I answered this question it did not mention Server 2003 or that Anthony needed an alternative to group policy. war59312's answer is more helpful than mine now that the question has been updated.

That said, the steps I outlined will still work with a Server 2003 domain as long as you have at least one machine running Server 2008 with the Group Policy Management Console installed (or a vista/7 client with RSAT). As explained in the [article](http://www.grouppolicy.biz/2010/12/group-policy-preferences-prerequisites/) he referenced.

Answer (score 2):

First, do like Curtis says.

You can then use this script to copy the file over to the computer.

Simply have it run as a startup script for awhile.

See Microsoft article on how to create a startup script @ https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779329(v=ws.10).aspx

It's 100% silent.

Create this as a .vbs file:

```
'THIS SCRIPT SILENTLY COPIES D:\Signature.txt TO %APPDATA%\MICROSOFT\Signatures

Option Explicit

Dim WshShell
Dim objFSO

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Install E-Mail Signature
WshShell.Run "cmd /c copy /Y D:\Signature.txt %APPDATA%\MICROSOFT\Signatures\", 0, true
```

Be sure and change "D:\Signature.txt" to the location of the original signature file that you want to copy to "%APPDATA%\MICROSOFT\Signatures\".

Note: This script will override any file that already exists in the Signatures folder. Assumed you want it to copy over no matter what.